# Import of csv data rows and columns when specyfing delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\sampledata.csv"

with open(filename, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(reader)
    data = []   
    for row in reader:
        measured_time = float(row[0])
        wv1 = float(row[1])
        wv2 = float(row[2])
        data.append([measured_time, wv1,wv2])

time=data[0]
y1=data[1]

plt.plot(time,y1)

plt.show()
```

Works just fine, but as this was a test before I work with the real data.

Now the real data doesn't have a header and consists on only 2 columns.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\real_data.csv"

with open(filename, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=';')
    data = []   
    for row in reader:
        measured_time = float(row[0])
        wv1 = float(row[1])
        data.append([measured_time, wv1])

time=data[0]
y1=data[1]

plt.plot(time,y1)

plt.show()
```

this yields

time=[100,1]

y1=[110,2]

so basically just the first 2 rows while the first codeblock correctly extracts the columns

time=[100 110 ...]

y1=[1 2 ...]

The same thing happens when I use

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\sampledata.csv"

with open(filename, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(reader)
    data = []   
    for row in reader:
        measured_time = float(row[0])
        wv1 = float(row[1])
        data.append([measured_time, wv1])

time=data[0]
y1=data[1]

plt.plot(time,y1)

plt.show()
```

For now my workaround is

```
data = np.array(data).astype("float")


time=data[:,0]
y1=data[:,1]
```

Surely there has to be a better way, I'm just starting with Python.

Data used:

```
sample data
Time,279 nm,306 nm
0,100,150
1,110,175
2,125,230
3,130,245

real data
3.986931e+002;0.000000e+000
4.021733e+002;0.000000e+000
```

Comment: Is `;` a delimiter used in the file? Are you sure you don't have errors in the data file?

Comment: Can you add few lines from the real file to the post

Comment: @Laszlowaty Yes ; is  the delimiter in the real data and I would exclude errors because with my mentioned workaround it works. @ Marco done

Comment: You are looking for `zip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list(zip())` allows to traspose a set of sequences:

```
time = [100, 1]
y1 = [110, 2]
l = list(zip(time, y1))
print(l) # [(100, 110), (1, 2)]
time = l[0] # (100, 110)
y1 = l[1] # (1, 2)
```

They are tuples that you can use as lists or you can transform them to lists:

```
time = list(l[0]) # [100, 110]
y1 = list(l[1]) # [1, 2]
```

If you want to get them straight into the opposite form you could swap the reading part:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\sampledata.csv"

with open(filename, newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # header = next(reader)
    time = []
    y1 = []   
    for row in reader:
        time.append( float(row[0]) )
        y1.append( float(row[1]) )

plt.plot(time,y1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate what exactly I've been changing that makes this necessary? I honestly don't see why it wouldn't work out the way I wrote it.

Comment: Provide the first lines from the csv file and I will elaborate more, without knowing the first lines I can only provide you with a way fo trasposing lists.

Comment: As per marco's request I updated my question earlier, what you see below real data are the first two lines of the csv I'm working with. What you see under sample data is the complete set.

Comment: Then with your script you are getting `time = [398.6931, 0.0]` and `y1 = [402.1733, 0.0]`. You want it the other way round? Check my updated answer.

Comment: with my sample data the columns get extracted, my real data only contains the first 2 lines. time = [398.6931 402.1733 ... ] and y1 [0 0 ...] would be what I desire.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it does that. Well, kind of, it gives `time = [398.6931, 402.1733]` and `y1 = [0.0, 0.0]` as you are transforming both to `float`s instead of `y1 = [0, 0]` as in your comment.

Comment: That works the way I intended it. Thank you! I'm still a little left behind on why exactly my code works only for the one file and not for the other. Why did my original code produce tupels? I already accepted the answer as it solves my problem, but understanding why would be a big plus for me.

Comment: It isn't you code, it's `zip()` the one creating the tuples. Tuples are a nice sequence container if you are not going to modify (modify means both creating or deleting elements or modifying an element) the sequence in any way. Note: you can actually modify mutable elements inside a tuple, but I didnt want to get too technical.

Comment: But in my original question I didn't even use `zip()` and ended up with tupels anyway / rows weren't read correctly.

Comment: No, in your original code you end up with lists. 2-element lists but still lists. Tuples are represented with parenthesis and lists with square brackets. You were using `data.append([measured_time, wv1])` (the parenthesis are for the function call, the square brackets form lists).

Comment: Okay, and that's why I had to convert afterwards again. However the contents of measured_time and wv1 were different for sampledata and realdata. See after my 2nd code block in my question. Why do I get 2 different results for (in my opinion) basically the same code? I have the feeling I can't correctly express my problem.

Comment: They have different delimiters, `,` vs `;`, have you used the correct one? If you have your code on the sample data should have yielded: `time = [0.0, 100.0]` and `y1 = [1.0, 110.0]` and mine would yield: `time = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` and `y1 = [100.0, 110.0, 125.0, 130.0]`

Comment: I used the correct delimiter. I printed the results and you were right, my code didn't work for the sample data as I intended. I don't know how I missed that yesterday. It is indeed the format suggested by you. Thanks!